# Calculus max rectangle

Tags: calculus

Consider a rectangle with sides $2x$ and $2y$ inscribed in a given fixed circle $x^2+y^2=a^2$ , and let $n$ be a positive number. We wish to find the rectangle that maximizes the quantity $z=x^n+y^n$ . If $n=2$ , it is clear that $z$ has the constant value $a^2$ for all rectangles. If $n<2$, show that the square maximizes $z$, and if $n>2$, show that $z$ is maximized by a degenerate rectangle in which x or y is zero.

My approach was;
  i took 1st and 2nd derivatives 
1st: $nx^{n-1}+ny^{n-1}y'$

2nd: $[n(n-1)x^{n-2}+n(n-1)y^{n-2}y'+y''ny^{n-1}]$

And tried to put $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ to the $y$ then took the derivatives  and that doesn't go anywhere too.

Answer (score 2):

Hint...you would find it a lot easier to do the differentiation and to analyse the different cases for $n$ if you first parametrized the variables using $$x=a\cos\theta,$$$$y=a\sin\theta$$

Answer (score 1):

By Lagrange multipliers:  Let $g(x,y) = x^2+y^2$ and $f(x,y) = x^n+y^n$.  First assume $x$ and $y$ are positive.  The constraint is $g = a^2$.  Since the case $n=2$ is done, assume $n \neq 2.$

We have $\nabla f = (nx^{n-1},ny^{n-1})$ and $\nabla g = (2x,2y).$ So the equation $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$ gives us

$$nx^{n-1} = \lambda 2x, \mbox{ and } ny^{n-1} = \lambda 2y.$$

Cancel an $x$ from the first equation and a $y$ from the second:

$$nx^{n-2} = \lambda 2, \mbox{ and } ny^{n-2} = \lambda 2.$$

Conclude that $x= y.$  Then $2x^2 = a^2$ and so $x= y = a/\sqrt{2}.$

So the critical points are $(a/\sqrt{2},a/\sqrt{2})$ and the points where either $x$ or $y$ equal zero.  Then

$$f(a/\sqrt{2},a/\sqrt{2}) = 2\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^n$$

and

$f(0,y) = y^n$ which is maximized when $y=a$.  Similarly for $f(x,0)$.  The max will be which ever value is greater.

Comment: I dont know lagrange bu it must be solved by taking derivatives

Comment: How about the case when $n > 2$?

Comment: @GNUSupporter  I don't get your objection.

Comment: OP asks a proof in which $z$ is maximised when $xy = 0$, but your conclusion is $x = y$.

Comment: @GNUSupporter  I just gave a sketch.  I've added some details, though.

Comment: I still don't get why $(x,y)$ is a critical point if $xy = 0$.  You assumed $x,y > 0$ at the beginning.

Comment: @GNUSupporter  I assumed $x,y >0$ because I was going to divide by them later.  The case $xy=0$ I left up to the student.  This is a boundary condition that you (if you care) need to check.  Like many people do when answering homework problems, I sketched the main part of the calculation.  I firmly believe that most of us think that is sufficient.